# Countdown Timer which resets every 12 hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, timer, countdown

I'm trying to make a custom countdown timer that resets itself every 12 hours and won't reset on every refresh or by closing the window.

**EXAMPLE -** Like I've a shopping site and want to show COUNTDOWN Timer there which shows in this format (hh:mm:ss) with unlimited loop ... and it must not reset by closing the browser or window.

I think the ideal way to do this is via timezone?

Any kind of solutions are welcomed...

I need exactly like this type of countdown timer - http://www.bedeals.com/

Comment: If you want it to be the same across clients and not change with refreshes. Then you are begging for a simple server that can deliver the time of the countdown. From there you use ajax to get updates to the countdown.

Answer (score 1):

You may persist the timer state in `localStorage` . Simply add the time of start there and every time you get into the page read the value and apply some functions to get current time ( based on obtained value ). The apply `setInterval` to update the timer on the page dynamically.

Date formatting is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532664/how-to-display-a-date-object-in-a-specific-format-using-javascript).