# JavaScript display date in a specific format

Tags: javascript

I have date as `2017-11-01`. I want to display it in `November 1, 2017` pattern. 
What is the best and short approach to achieve it.

Comment: please share and show us what you have tried.

Comment: let try [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), it solve everything about datetime :)!

Comment: Try this `var date = new Date("2017-11-01"),
    month = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: "long" }),
    formattedDate = month + ' ' + date.getDate() +', ' + date.getFullYear();`

Comment: @HassanImam—note that 2017-11-01 will most likely be parsed as UTC, but you are getting local values based on the host timezone offset, so the result may appear to be ±1 day.

Comment: See [*Convert date format in Javascript using VueJS*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708110/convert-date-format-in-javascript-using-vuejs). There is also [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @RobG Forgot to add that bit. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should dig in SO. Its clearly answered question. 
in here

[Your Question answer in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532664/how-to-display-a-date-object-in-a-specific-format-using-javascript)

1st. You can use library as mention above [Moment.Js](http://momentjs.com/) is only 5.5kb minified so its cool to use

2nd.If you dont want use library just go see  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527956/6350299) answer

Comment: If it's a duplicate, mark it as a duplicate. But the OP doesn't have a Date, they have a string.